# how to get value from url after using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, url, routes

I am trying to make functionality used by routes by my own.

I have some url say,

> $url1 = /profile/user/10/
>
> $url2 = /profile/{some_variable}/settings/{some_integer}

Regular expression for url1,

> '/profile/user/[0-9]+/$/'

Regular expression for url2

> '/profile/[a-z]+/settings/[0-9]+/$/'

Description,
I am trying to check whether a certain url exists or not in my routes folder which I can achieve by using preg_match() between by url and the regular expression.

I want to get the value '10' from

> $url1 = /profile/user/10/

and {some_variable}, {some_integer} from

> $url2 = /profile/{some_variable}/settings/{some_integer}

So that I can pass these variables in my controller function.

Please help.

Edit: I have an array which holds regular expressions for URLs, When a url is hit, I get that url and match it inside the array whether it exists or not. If it does I need to get the variables used in url.

```
Array (
    [specific_user] => Array
        (
            [url] => /profile\/user\/[0-9]+\/$/
            [className] => user
            [methodName] => userinfo
        )

    [specific_user_check] => Array
        (
            [url] => /profile\/user\/[a-z]+\/$/
            [className] => user
            [methodName] => userinfo
        )

    [user_settings] => Array
        (
            [url] => /profile\/user\/settings\/$/
            [className] => user
            [methodName] => settings
        )  )
```

Here,

> $myUrl = /profile/user/10/

if $myUrl matches with the regular expression in array, then I need to get  value '10'.

Note: (.*) is used somehow to get the desired result.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what problems are you having with it?

Comment: You regex are incorrect and you need to escape `/` as `\/` if your delimiters are `/`

Comment: Which framework you are using

Comment: @NigelRen I want to get the value '10' from $url1 = /profile/user/10/ when I compare it with '/profile/user/[0-9]+/$/'

Comment: @RahulMeshram, I am not using any framework, I am trying to make the functionality used by frameworks for Routes by using PHP.

Comment: You are just stating what you want and not what you have tried.

Comment: preg_match_all()

Comment: @NigelRen: check my edit.

Comment: Have you tried using capture groups?

Comment: @NigelRen: I have seen it but do not how to use it, can you please elaborate the same using my example?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going for regular expression, you can easily achieve this by a PHP function `explode()`.

Here the code example

```
$url2 = "/profile/some_variable/settings/10";

$url_values = explode("/",$url2);

$variable = $url_values[2];
$integer = $url_values[4];
```

if you are not sure about the indexes, you can loop though the array and find value coming on next index to ***profile*** and ***settings***